# If a and b are two positive integers, prove $a^2-4b \neq 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I know that there are answers for this question, but I didn't come across the following proof, and I was wondering if it was correct:

I re-arranged the equation: $a^2 \neq 2 \pmod 4$

Case 1: when a is even:

let $a = 2k$ where $k \in Z$

$(2k)^2 \neq 2\pmod4$

$4k^2 \neq 2\pmod4$

$4(k^2) \neq 2\pmod4$

the statement is true because LHS does not have a remainder 2.

Caes 2: when a is odd

let $a = 2k+1$ where $k \in Z$

$(2k+1)^2 \neq 2\pmod4 $

$4k^2 + 4k + 1 \neq 2\pmod4$

$4(k^2 + k) + 1 \neq 2\pmod4$

the LHS has a remainder of 1 when divided by 4 and the RHS has a remainder of 2 which does not equal $\therefore$ the statement is true

Comment: Yeah, looks fine to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with [Parcly Taxel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/357390/parcly-taxel)'s comment that it basically looks fine.

My only suggestion is to not use what you're trying to prove in each part as this makes it appear you've already shown, and thus don't need to go on, or you're assuming initially what you're trying to prove. Thus, for the first part of $a = 2k$, I would instead do something like $(2k)^2 = 4k^2 \equiv 0 \not\equiv 2 \pmod 4$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean by: 'assuming what you're trying to prove' Could you rephrase your sentence.

Comment: @ph-quiett I've rephrased my sentence somewhat. This is not a major issue, but note you are trying to prove, for example, that $(2k)^2 \not\equiv 2 \pmod 4$. However, your first statement indicates this is already known to be true, but it's only shown later on. In a relatively simple proof like this it doesn't really matter too much. Nonetheless, I would suggest trying to avoid doing this as it can cause potential issues if you do something similar with more complicated proofs.

Comment: oh I understand that my " first statement indicates this is already known to be true" so how would I exactly fix this? $(2k)^2 = 4k^2 ≡ 0 \neq 2 (mod 4)$ doesn't quite make sense to me

Comment: @ph-quiett The statement I gave of $(2k)^2 = 4k^2 \equiv 0 \not\equiv 2 \pmod 4$ should be read from left to right. It says first that $(2k)^2 = 4k^2$, then that $4k^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ and that $0 \not\equiv 2 \pmod 4$. If it helps you see this, you can write those parts on separate lines instead of combining them as I did.

Answer (score 1):

Your method looks okay.  Or you could say $a\equiv0, 1, 2, $ or $3\pmod4$ so $a^2\equiv0, 1, 0, $ or $1\pmod4,$ not $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Our OP's proof looks fine to me, however:

We don't really need to consider the even and odd cases separately.

If

$a^2 - 4b = 2 \tag 1$

for

$a, b \in \Bbb N, \tag 2$

we may write

$a^2 = 4b + 2 = 2(2b + 1) \Longrightarrow 2 \mid a; \tag 3$

$2 \mid a \Longrightarrow 4 \mid a^2 \Longrightarrow 4 \mid a^2 - 4b \Longrightarrow 4 \mid 2; \tag 4$

however,

$4 \mid 2 \tag 5$

is impossible; hence, no such $a, b \in \Bbb N$ exist.  $OE\Delta.$

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate take:

$a^2-4b = 2$ implies $a^2=2+4b=2(1+2b)$ and so $2v_2(a)=1$, which is impossible.

Here, $v_2(n)$ is the exponent of $2$ in the prime factorization of $n$.